# How to connect MongoDB through Tableau Public Version 'Odata'

Tags: mongodb, odata, tableau-desktop

I am now working on the Tableau Public version. I want to connect my MongoDB through the tableau public edition, but I don't find any connections for MongoDB in the free version, even though there is an option "'OData"' through which I want to configure API for MongoDB so that I can connect the tables for the visualizations. The resources listed below do not assist me in this regard. I appreciate it if someone helps me with this?
Note: I am using Tableau Public(free version)

https://community.tableau.com/s/

https://www.tableau.com/support/public

Comment: Can someone help me with this?